# My icons dont show up (Material-ui). Can someone guide me on how should I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to ask you why my icons don't show up in C# react. I was trying a whole lot of different solutions, and none of them worked for me. Maybe one of you knows the solution and how to fix it. [Link to original implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-59p6m?file=/demo.js) This is the code which I'm working on:`

```
return (
    <MaterialTable
        title="Editable Example"
        columns={state.columns}
        data={state.data}
        editable={{
            onRowAdd: (newData) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve();
                        setState((prevState) => {
                            const data = [...prevState.data];
                            data.push(newData);
                            return { ...prevState, data };
                        });
                    }, 600);
                }),
            onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve();
                        if (oldData) {
                            setState((prevState) => {
                                const data = [...prevState.data];
                                data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                return { ...prevState, data };
                            });
                        }
                    }, 600);
                }),
            onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve();
                        setState((prevState) => {
                            const data = [...prevState.data];
                            data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                            return { ...prevState, data };
                        });
                    }, 600);
                }),
        }}
    />
);
```

}`
[image: Picture of what is shown]

Answer (score 1):

if the icons are missing: double check your `index.html` file, if you find this line:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have included these lines.

Answer (score 0):

open a browser like Google Chrome.

Hit `F12` and go to **Network**-Tab.

Look for any errors indicating a error when you load the font.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question. Heres the code:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

const tableIcons = {
Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
};
...
        <MaterialTable
        icons={tableIcons}
...
```